# Capturing changes to model using angular-google-places-autocomplete

Tags: autocomplete, angularjs-directive, google-places-api, ionic-framework

I'm using angular-google-places-autocomplete (https://github.com/kuhnza/angular-google-places-autocomplete) with Ionic but having problems capturing the selected option when using this directive.

I have the directive set up like this:

```
<!-- template -->
<input type="text" placeholder="Place search" g-places-autocomplete ng-model="locationSearchResult"/>

<h5>Result</h5>
<pre ng-bind="locationSearchResult | json"></pre>
```

My controller code is set up to watch for changes to the locationSearchResult model, and if it does change to save the new location to local storage:

```
// Controller
$scope.locationSearchResult = {};    

$scope.$watch('locationSearchResult', function(newVal, oldVal) {
  if (angular.equals(newVal, oldVal)) { return; }
  $scope.$storage.loc = newVal;
  $state.go('new-page');
```

});

When using the autocomplete it seems to work as expected - I get a list of predictions, and selecting a prediction from the list of predictions updates the text input with the name of the selected place, and the JSON data for the selected place displays under the result heading. But, the change doesn't seem to be picked up by the $scope.$watch in the controller.

As a result, I can't seem to be able to capture the search result data and do anything with it - like add it to the user session.

Maybe I'm just going about it the wrong way (though I used the same approach with ngAutocomplete and it worked ok).

Answer (score 8):

Use the event that gets emitted in your controller.

```
$scope.$on('g-places-autocomplete:select', function (event, param) {
  console.log(event);
  console.log(param);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan. I moved away from using this directive and started using a hacked version of https://github.com/israelidanny/ion-google-place

Good to have this here for others using this directive, though.

Comment: @onblur - were you able get business listings ?  I can get cities and addresses but not businesses.  If yes, can you please provide a code sample?

Comment: Hi @JotiBasi - yes, I was able to get business listings. See the discussion here: https://github.com/israelidanny/ion-google-place/issues/3 and code in this PR: https://github.com/israelidanny/ion-google-place/pull/15